# Dynamically create multiple dropdowns angularjs from a single JSON file

Tags: angularjs, select, filter, ng-options

I have a list of categoryTypes and each categoryType has a list of categories within them and i am displaying them in a dropdown which the user can select multiple items from and the choices made will filter what apps are shown in the view (this is an inhouse appstore)

This is the JSON file im working with.

> [{"type":"category","id":1181,"categoryType":{"id":1180,"name":"Technology"},"name":"Spotfire"},{"type":"category","id":1182,"categoryType":{"id":1180,"name":"Technology"},"name":"PipelinP"},{"type":"category","id":1184,"categoryType":{"id":1183,"name":"Category"},"name":"IBSI"},{"type":"category","id":1185,"categoryType":{"id":1183,"name":"Category"},"name":"Clin"},{"type":"category","id":1187,"categoryType":{"id":1186,"name":"Capability"},"name":"Chemistry"},{"type":"category","id":1188,"categoryType":{"id":1183,"name":"Category"},"name":"Key
>   Opinion
>   Leaders"},{"type":"category","id":1189,"categoryType":{"id":1183,"name":"Category"},"name":"Pnts"},{"type":"category","id":1190,"categoryType":{"id":1183,"name":"Category"},"name":"CI"},{"type":"category","id":1191,"categoryType":{"id":1180,"name":"Technology"},"name":"VantageP"},{"type":"category","id":1192,"categoryType":{"id":1183,"name":"Category"},"name":"Targets"},{"type":"category","id":1193,"categoryType":{"id":1186,"name":"Capability"},"name":"Information
>   Science"},{"type":"category","id":1194,"categoryType":{"id":1186,"name":"Capability"},"name":"DMP"},{"type":"category","id":1195,"categoryType":{"id":1180,"name":"Technology"},"name":"Spotfire
>   Web
>   Player"},{"type":"category","id":1196,"categoryType":{"id":1186,"name":"Capability"},"name":"PredictiveS"},{"type":"category","id":1198,"categoryType":{"id":1197,"name":"Function"},"name":"PharmD"},{"type":"category","id":1199,"categoryType":{"id":1197,"name":"Function"},"name":"iM
>   - CV/GI"},{"type":"category","id":1200,"categoryType":{"id":1180,"name":"Technology"},"name":"Mobile
>   Apps"},{"type":"category","id":1201,"categoryType":{"id":1197,"name":"Function"},"name":"RAPIDE"},{"type":"category","id":1202,"categoryType":{"id":1197,"name":"Function"},"name":"iM
>   - Oncology"},{"type":"category","id":1203,"categoryType":{"id":1186,"name":"Capability"},"name":"Clin"}]

But because an admin can add categoryTypes and categories to any type the dropdowns need to be dynamically created as they were hard coded. There needs to be a new dropdown for each Category Type.

So what i was able to do was have all categories shown in one dropdown grouped by category type with this;

```
<select class="form-control"  multiple class="span4 chzn-select" chosen="myCategories" data-placeholder=" "  ng-model="c"  ng-options="c.name group by c.categoryType.name for c in myCategories">
```

I created the factory to get the categories;

```
.factory('categoryFactory', function ($resource) {
        return $resource(
                '/resources/appstore/categories'  
        );
    })
```

The controller looks like this;

```
$scope.myCategories = [];

  categoryFactory.query(function (d) {
            $scope.myCategories = d;
        });
```

So for example take the first line of the JSON.

The  the category of 'Spotfire' is in the categoryType 'Technology'.

So for that categorytype i would need the dropdown of technology which shows at least spotfire + whatever else is parsed in the JSON file being in that categoryType.

Then another dropdown for the next categoryType and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternate version rendering each select individually. It's using a custom `groupBy` filter (using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)):

```
app.filter('groupBy', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return function groupByFilter(input, groupByExpr) {
    return _.groupBy(input, $parse(groupByExpr));
  };
}]);
```

with:

```
<div ng-repeat="(categoryTypeName, categories) in groupedCategories track by categoryTypeName">
  <label>{{categoryTypeName}}</label>

  <select
    ng-model="selected[categoryTypeName]"
    ng-options="c as c.name for c in categories track by c.id"
    multiple
  ></select>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the filter has to be applied when the the data changes,

```
$scope.$watchCollection('categories', function (categories) {
  $scope.groupedCategories = groupByFilter(categories, 'categoryType.name');
});
```

because if used with `ng-repeat` directly angular will complain about an *Infinite $digest Loop*.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ipfVfH3pbLoYk1u4n3la?p=preview

On the other hand, given your requirements, it would be a lot simpler if your json would already be structured the way you need it (category types with a list of child-categories, not the other way around).

---

*original answer*:

I can't really picture your final layout, but a simple starting point could be the `group by` feature of [`ng-options`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect).

E.g.:

```
<select
  ng-model="selected"
  ng-options="c as c.name group by c.categoryType.name for c in categories track by c.id" 
></select>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JA8DspuVQMRhmKK9YN6r?p=preview

Comment: What i want is for each category type to have its own dropdown box with only those categories in it.

So there should be at the minute 4 seperate dropdowns generated and if an admin adds a new caategoryType then a new dropdown should be generated on loading the page.

I have uploaded an image of what i have at the minute which is all hardcoded but this is what i am trying to get it to look like;

http://i.imgur.com/Lj3iKKc.jpg

Comment: @user2964618 is good demo and you can easily achieve what you interesting based on this example

Comment: @user2964618 I see, I'll update my answer shortly. Though you'll at the very least need some custom filters to achieve that. ;)

Comment: @sawyer762 just leave another comment, I think we should be able to open a chat then.

Comment: @Yoshi didnt see that :), i'm having an issue that i cant use the selected values to filter the ng-repeat list of apps that i have. Whenever i select a few tags or even just one and i log whats chosen it just says "undefined" and so i cant use the selected value to filter by. I'm using the ng-model name as the filter:... but its acting as though nothing is selected.

Comment: @sawyer762 I have a feeling that this should be a new question. Though what I can say is that, because `selected` will be an object, I doubt it can be used as a filter value.

Comment: @Yoshi Ok thanks alot. I made the new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049463/using-a-object-on-ng-repeat-as-a-filter